# Structure in c K&R page no.129

Tags: c, struct

I am learning c from K&R and have reached page no.1129 where the following code is listed.

```
struct rect {
  struct point pt1;
  struct point pt2;
};
```

What it does mean?

Comment: It's a mystery......  mainly 'cos you did not look up the declaration of the 'point' struct.

Comment: @MartinJames Looked but why point pt given also as a strcut  again ?

Comment: ... which is probably a couple of ints for the coordinates of top-left and bottom-right.

Comment: @MartinJames Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @Gireesh Kumar  By the way how many pages is there in the book?

Comment: Unless you have `typedef`ed a `struct`, you refer to it as `struct point pt1` for example. And when you define an instance of a rectangle, it will be with `struct rect rec1` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What it does mean ?

It means that `rect` is a `struct`. It has two members - `pt1` and `pt2`. `pt1` and `pt2` are of type `struct point`.

> Looked but why point pt given also as a `struct` ?

When you declare variables of type `struct` you have two options:

1. Use the long form, like you have.
2. Define a `typedef` and use a shorter form.

   ```
   typedef struct point point;

   struct rect {
     point pt1;
     point pt2;
   };
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**Short Version**

```
struct rect {
  struct point pt1;
  struct point pt2;
};
```

creates a new structure type named `struct rect`, consisting of the members `pt1` and `pt2`, each of which has type `struct point`.

The `struct` keyword is part of the type name, and must be present when you declare `pt1` and `pt2`.

**Not So Short Version**

In C, most type names are reserved words – `int`, `float`, `char`, etc. – and cannot be used for any other purpose; that is, you can't name a variable or a function `int`.

However, the *tag name* for a `struct` type (`point` and `rect` in the code above) is *not* a reserved word; it's an identifer that could also be used as a variable or function name, or in other contexts.  For the C compiler to know you're talking about the `point` *type* and not a `point` *variable*, you need to include the `struct` keyword.

C has four different *name spaces*; that is, four different contexts in which the same identifier can be used without causing a conflict:

- Label names;
- Tag names for `struct`, `union`, and `enum` types;
- Member names for structures and unions;
- Ordinary identifiers (variable names, function names, typedef names, enumeration constants).

Thus, the following code is legal (if a *really* bad idea):

```
      struct foo { int foo; int bar; } foo;
      ...
      goto foo;
      ...
foo:  printf( "foo.foo = %d\n", foo.foo );
```

The compiler *disambiguates* (distinguishes between) the different uses of `foo` as follows:

- The *label* `foo` is disambiguated by the `goto` keyword and trailing `:`;
- The *tag name* `foo` is disambiguated by the `struct` keyword;
- The *member name* `foo` is disambiguated by the `.` member selection operator;
- And the *ordinary identifier* `foo` is disambiguated by not fitting any of the previous cases.

Thus, if you want to refer to the *types* `struct point` and `struct rect`, the `struct` keyword must be present; otherwise the compiler will think you're talking about a *variable* named `point` or `rect` and get confused.

You can create a typedef name as an alias or synonym of `struct point`:

```
struct point { ... };
typedef struct point point;
```

Now the identifier `point` is an alias for the type `struct point`, allowing you to declare points as

```
point pt1, pt2;
```

Note that in the ordinary identifier namespace, you *cannot* do something this:

```
typedef struct point { ... } point;
point point;
```

because in that namespace, `point` may either be a typedef name *or* a variable name, but not both.

However, gcc is letting me get away with the following:

```
typedef struct point { ... } point;
typedef struct rect { point point; } rect;
```

because in this case, the second instance of `point` in the `rect` type definition is in the member name namespace, not the ordinary identifier namespace.